# Are lower rep users allowed to comment on higher rep users' questions & answers?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

I'm trying to comment on [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/22519/9302) but my comment keeps disappearing.

All my comment is trying to point out is that the first part of the answer is irrelevant since the original poster's quote is asking about the rate of returns of a short vs long while the answer sidetracks to calculating rate of return using margin as cost.

Why would my comments be deleted?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, users with sufficient reputation (>50) are permitted to comment on any post (except posts that get locked.)

Your comments didn't disappear.

I read your comments, considered them, and exercised my prerogative as a moderator to delete them.

Your choice of words (e.g. *"completely irrelevant"*, and *"ridiculously calculated"*) weren't constructive.

Comment: lulz.  these site will go the way of yahoo answers

Comment: *Au contraire* -- that's why we clean up posts and comments.

Comment: And I take it the user deleted his account already?

Comment: Can a user delete his account, along with all his questions/answers, without approval? I wouldn't think we would want *all* questions/answers of any given user to disappear.

Comment: @JohnBensin Generally speaking, a user can't delete his own profile if anything has been posted. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).  So, I'm supposing he requested the Stack Exchange community team to delete his profile here, and they agreed.  (And let me add -- I was surprised myself at this outcome!)

Comment: Is the new CEO Meyers buying StackExchange too?

Comment: When a new user starts by lobbing insults or immediately asking to change what's on-topic, I'm inclined to think,"maybe this site isn't for you."